# Specifying behaviour of a Back button per view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am having several view controllers, call them 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. I made an `UINavigationController`  and it have a back button. The back button appears on each view controller (I never hide it).

Right now I am having situation like this. I go from 1,2,3,4,5 then back to 3. Just as an additional information, the transition from 5 to 3 is done using manual segue (but sometimes I use other segues, like push, or modal). If I hit the back button on that view controller, normally it will go to 5, because of how stacking works. But I want to be able to specify that from view controller 3, you always go to vc 2 when Back button is tapped...

I guess that manipulating navigation stack here could be a way to go (based on a current view controller), but I don't know is that ideal, or there is something more appropriate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass and override some of the methods in [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) to get a callback when the back button is pressed. Then you can force the navigation controller to respond how you want.

For instance, when `popViewController(animated:)` is called, you can determine based on view controllers (or however you want) whether you should actually allow the normal back button functionality. If you want normal behavior, just call `super`. In the case of going from view controller 3 to view controller 2 (instead of view controller 5), you would not call `super`, and instead do `popToViewController(viewController2, animated: animated)`.

Comment: I ended up doing it like this... Tried some other ways, but this was easiest and cleanest to implement. At least for me.

Comment: I just noticed a warning in console, which says : *Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.* This is happening if I do popToViewController(vc2, animated:animated). If I set animated to false, the message disappears, but back button disappears as well. I guess it is some kind of race condition. Any idea how to get rid of this message without loosing a Back button?

Answer (score 2):

Typically when I want to "jump" back more than one view I have used "delegation". What you really want to do is pop several off the stack not just segue to where you want to go.

What I would recommend is delegate method on each VC that gets passed through. ie VC 1 can dismiss VC 2, VC 2 can dismiss VC 3 etc. Then when you are on VC 5 you call navigateToView(index: Int) you do a quick check and if they view controller that responds to that delegate call matches that index then you just pop the previously displayed VC and you are good. If not you pop the previously displayed VC and then call that VC delegate method until you get to where you want to be.

A common design pattern is the VC that is responsible for displaying another VC is the one that determines if it should be dismissed. This also gives you flexibility to update UI if needed before going back to previous views.

Hopefully that makes some sense and is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

replace the back button with your own custom button and you can set the action to perform a segue back to 3. Or you can use the navigation controllers children stack to go back to 3, which ever you prefer.

in the view controller add this code:

```
let backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(viewController.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:)))

    viewController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButton, animated: true)
```

Currently the action will use the default behaviour and pop back one. However you can change this with your own method and perform a segue back to 3.

Comment: I just deleted my comment, because it was irrelevant. I misinterpreted what you meant by *segue*, so I get what you are saying now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider you have opened VC's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Than you open VC 3. 
So you have such `UINavigationController` `controllers` stack [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]

If you want to have back transition to `UIViewController` #3 you may just remove controllers #3, #4 and #5 (from the middle of your navigation stack) at the moment of transition finish #3.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
       self.navigationController.delegate = self
}

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: navigationController.viewControllers];
//Navigation stack now is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]. removing VC #3
        [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex: 2];

//Navigation stack now is [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]. removing VC #4
        [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex: 2];

//Navigation stack now is [1, 2, 5, 3].removing VC #5
        [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex: 2];

//Navigation stack now is [1, 2, 3]
navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;

}
```

Having removed view controllers from navigation stack you'll get back transition from 3 to 2